# Terminology - how do you call a thread blocked waiting on an event that never happens

Tags: concurrency, terminology

If a thread is waiting on a condition, a future, a countdown latch forever (because of a bug in the logic that should have asynchronously notified the condition, completed the future, counted the latch down to zero, etc.), what is the correct name for this? Deadlock? Livelock? Something else?

Specifically, it feels wrong to call something that is not in a tie a deadlock, yet also something that is actually blocked a livelock, but it would be nice to have a specific enough term that sets these two apart.

Comment: Starvation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)

Comment: @BurakSerdar - thanks for the link. It does not seem like a perfect term because nothing is "starved", waiting threads are just never receiving a notification.

Comment: That is the definition of starvation, though. If a waiting thread never gets a chance to run, either because of a bug or because of unfair scheduling, it is starved.

Comment: Say a process waits for a condition that is never fulfilled. This is obviously not a deadlock where >= 2 processes block each other by requesting a resource that another process holds, it is not a livelock, where >= 2 processes block each other because they use a deadlock avoidance strategy that does not let them continue, and it is not starvation, because no other process hinders the system to continue. This is to my mind simply a programming error without a special name. Example: A function with a callback, which misses to call this callback when finished. Does it deserve a special name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124159508), section 8.2.2, there is a problem like what you describe, where it's called a "lost wakeup":

> Just as locks are inherently vulnerable to deadlock, Condition objects are inherently vulnerable to lost wakeups, in which one or more threads wait forever without realizing that the condition for which they are waiting has become true.

The context in the book is narrow, it's talking specifically about checking condition variables when locking. But it doesn't seem like much of a stretch to extend its use to any case where something is hanging out anticipating an event that never comes.

On SO I've heard this type of bug referred to as "lost notifications" or "missed signals".

I would not call this situation starvation because the missed signal isn’t in itself a system resource that the thread puts to use to do work once it has woken up.  Resources are things like CPU time or memory or file handles or other things it could need in order to do its work. OS threads are themselves resources and this bug can result in taking threads out of play, if the lost wake up bug happens to enough threads it can eventually result in something getting starved.

Comment: Definitely better than "deadlock", "starvation", and imprecise "hangup". I'll use this one going forward. Thanks for digging it up.